# Angular Material Datepicker md-current-view not working

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material Datepicker, and I'm trying to display the "year" view (which display months instead of days) when opening the datepicker :

```
 <md-datepicker required ng-model="departureDate"
                                                       md-current-view="year"
                                                       md-placeholder="Date de départ"
                                                       md-open-on-focus class="col-md-6"></md-datepicker>
                                        <md-datepicker required ng-model="leavingDate"
                                                       md-current-view="year"
                                                       md-placeholder="Date de retour"
                                                       md-open-on-focus class="col-md-6"></md-datepicker>
```

However, It  doesnt work. I searched over the git repo issues, didn't find any solution about that, nor any reason why it behave like this.

Comment: What version of `angular-material` are you using? From versions `1.1.0` and up only have the attribute `md-current-view`: https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0/api/directive/mdDatepicker

Comment: @Edric I'm using the latest, which is 1.1.0 (or it's the latest available on googleapis)

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

Comment: Try giving it a `md-min-date` and `md-max-date`.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and was using version 1.1.0.

I upgraded to 1.1.8 and the issue was fixed straight away.

Hope that helps,

Sam